# Is there a testthat expect_* function for comparing two objects behavior?

Tags: r, unit-testing, functional-programming, testthat

I am writing some unit tests for an R package using `testthat`. I would like to compare two objects where not all the details need to match, but they must maintain equivalence with respect to a set of functions of interest.

For a simple example, I want to use something like

```r
library(testthat)

x <- 1:4
y <- matrix(4:1, nrow=2)

test_that("objects behave similarly", {
  expect_equal_applied(x, y, .fn=list(sum, prod))

  ## which would be shorthand for:
  ## expect_equal(sum(x), sum(y))
  ## expect_equal(prod(x), prod(y))
})
```

In practice, `x` and `y` might be S3 objects, not simply base data structures.

Obviously, this is simple to implement, but I'd prefer something idiomatic if already existing. So, the question is, **does `testthat` implement an expect function like this?**

Searching through the API, nothing struck me as fitting this description, but it seems like a natural pattern. Or maybe there is a reason why such a pattern is objectionable that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/index.html) {testthat} has currently (third edition) no function like `expect_equal_applied`. But, as you mention already, we can construct such a function easily:

```r
library(testthat)

x <- 1:4
y <- matrix(4:1, nrow=2)


expect_equal_applied <- function(object, expected, fns) {
  fns <- purrr::map(fns, rlang::as_function)
  purrr::map(fns, ~ expect_equal(.x(object), .x(expected)))
}

test_that("objects behave similarly", {
  expect_equal_applied(x, y, fns = list(sum, prod))
})
#> Test passed

x <- 1:3

test_that("objects behave similarly", {
  expect_equal_applied(x, y, fns = list(sum, prod))
})

#> -- Failure (<text>:19:3): objects behave similarly -----------------------------
#> .x(object) not equal to .x(expected).
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 6 - 10 == -4
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. global::expect_equal_applied(x, y, fns = list(sum, prod))
#>  2. purrr::map(fns, ~expect_equal(.x(object), .x(expected)))
#>  3. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(.x(object), .x(expected))
#> 
#> -- Failure (<text>:19:3): objects behave similarly -----------------------------
#> .x(object) not equal to .x(expected).
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 6 - 24 == -18
#> Backtrace:
#>  1. global::expect_equal_applied(x, y, fns = list(sum, prod))
#>  2. purrr::map(fns, ~expect_equal(.x(object), .x(expected)))
#>  3. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
#>  4. testthat::expect_equal(.x(object), .x(expected))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Regarding why such a function seems to be missing in {testthat}, I think that it isn't really necessary given, that we can construct it with `lapply` or `map`.